# How to get file type on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

I need to get file type without using file extensions on linux. There is "file" utility, which can do this. How can I do the same using C/C++? Not 'system(const char *)', of course... Thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK `file` is implemented over `libmagic`. For more reference see:

- `file` sources
- and maybe this link: http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic.

Comment: The link is the key.  It basically provides all of the funtionality of `file` in a library.

Answer (score 1):

Either call `file` as a child process or emulate what it does. There are no other options if you want to intelligently examine a file's content to guess what it contains.